# AWS Glue Crawler poor performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, glue-crawler

We're having some issues with one of our Glue crawlers

Crawler details:

```
- source: S3 path
- output: Glue table
- mode: incremental
- schedule: daily
```

We are using the crawler to load the new daily partitions and update the Glue catalog.
The S3 path is as follow: `s3://<bucket>/<directory>/`
with String partitions:

```
date
   hour
      customer_id (~800 per hour)
```

which means that each hour we're having 800 new partitions to load for each customer
in 24 hours total it's 800*24=19.2K partitions.

The crawler worked perfectly for a while but lately, the execution duration increased (~14 hours) and the crawler eventually fails on:

```
ERROR : Internal Service Exception.
```

Currently, the Glue table holds 3,384,101 partitions.

Even crawling a small amount of partition takes forever and eventually fails.

I believe it happens due to the high number of partitions we are using but,
is there any way to improve the crawling performance,
so it will deal with the huge amount of partitions added on a daily basis?

Thanks

Comment: That is a huge amount of partitions. Is that really necessary?

Comment: Scan  small sample size from each folder, rather then all possible files.

Comment: @Marcin each partition contains 1 Parquet file so the sample size won't affect this scenario.

Comment: @RobertKossendey this is the provided s3 input 
we are splitting the data by customer, I believe that writing the data to S3 in a different partition structure can help in this situation. but I wanna know if there is anything we can do to help the crawler in this current S3 partitioning.
Or Glue crawler can't handle this partitions load

Comment: I think you are misusing the partition feature, that is why you have performance problems. I don't think that this partition is bringing any value and you should change it.

Comment: @RobertKossendey can I change the partitions of the Glue table without changing the format of the S3 partitions?

Comment: No, the Glue Partitions are based on the S3 partitions as far as I know

Comment: We should not use primary key like customer id for partition. Creating very small parquet files are going to reduce your performance and you are also going to use more space as parquet file also stores metadata. Temporary solution to solve your problem is to scan only incremental folders and run your crawler multiple times in a day. please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/incremental-crawls.html